# What does this three-number isotope notation mean?

Tags: notation

What does the superscript $3+$ mean?
$$_{21}^{45}\mathrm{Sc}^{3+}$$

I understand that $45$ is the atomic mass number and $21$ is the number of protons. Is the $3+$ to indicate that it is a particular isotope, or does it have some other meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The superscript '$3+$' denotes a normalised [electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge). Charges are [quantised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge#Quantization), that is they take on only certain discrete values.

- Neutrons do not have a net charge ($q = 0 $).
- Electrons and protons have the same absolute charge<sup>[footnote]</sup>. They have opposite, arbitrary signs. By historical convention, protons are assigned positive charges.

Hence,

$$\text{electric charge} = \text{no. of protons} - \text{no. of electrons.}$$

For shorthand purposes, we usually normalise the electric charge by dividing the total electric charge of our agreed system with the elementary charge $e$.<sup>[footnote]</sup> This provides us an opportunity to operate with integer values in chemistry; there are fractional charges for quarks which were discovered later but these particles [cannot be observed separately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) by current understanding.

Note also that we write '$3+$' instead of '$+3$' since we are, again by convention, [counting charges](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/24773/27806) (that is $+ + + $), not denoting the mathematical normalised charge itself.

---

As of 2011, [this is verified up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/379796/106128) to essentially $1$ part in $10^{21}$. The absolute charge of an electron (or charge of a proton) is called *the elementary charge* $e$, and

$$e=1.6021766208(98) \cdot 10^{-19}\ \mathrm{C}$$

where the parentheses designate a standard uncertainty (assuming a normal distribution, $\approx 0.68$ probability, coverage factor $k =1$).

**ref**: Mohr, P. J.; Newell, D. B.; Taylor, B. N. 'CODATA Recommended Values of the Fundamental Physical Constants: 2014'. *Reviews of Modern Physics*, **2016**, 88 (3). DOI: [10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035009](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035009), freely available on arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07956v1), also [archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180106185134/https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07956v1.pdf).

> **Disclaimer:** originally, I claimed that proton–electron charge symmetry is verified up to $1$ part in $10^{26}$. This **was wrong**, and based on a naive approach. Again, see [How accurately is it known that protons have the same charge as electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379796/how-accurately-is-it-known-that-protons-have-the-same-charge-as-electrons) for a correction.

Comment: +1 For the OP's benefit, perhaps it'd help to point out that what he's dealing with is called an ["ion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion) ;-)